# how to reload after "from <module> import *"?

Tags: python, module, python-import

I can simply reload module when normally imported (imp.reload(*module or alias*)).
But is it possible to reload everything after imported into current namespace (from *module* import *) ?

imp.reload(*module*) doesn't work saying that "name: *module* is not defined"

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516783/how-to-reload-python-module-imported-using-from-module-import?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do `from module import *` everything from that module is fetched into the current namespace and at the end the reference to `module` is removed. But, due to module caching the module object can still be accessed from `sys.modules`, so that in case you do some more import later one than it doesn't have to fetch the module again.

That said, one way to do what you're expecting is:

```
import sys
from foo import *
print A, B        #prints 1, 2
A, B = 100, 200
mod = reload(sys.modules['foo'])#use imp.reload for Python 3  
vars().update(mod.__dict__)     #update the global namespace
print A, B        #prints 1, 2
```

As a side note, using `import *` is [usually frowned upon](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules):

> Note that in general the practice of importing * from a module or
>   package is frowned upon, since it often causes poorly readable code.
>   However, it is okay to use it to save typing in interactive sessions.

Comment: Yes. I use it for interactive session only. I'm a C++ guy, I'm aware of the danger of importing everything from namespace. Thanks!