# How to tell Python to reimport my script?

Tags: python

I ran my script from Python environment launched in bash:

```
>>> import myscript
```

I then modified my script a little and save it. Then run again

```
>>> import myscript
```

But it doesn't run the updated script.

How can I tell Python to run the updated one? Thanks!

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516783/how-to-reload-python-module-imported-using-from-module-import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) it like this

```
reload(myscript)
```

Quoting from the docs,

> Reload a previously imported module. The argument must be a module object, so it must have been successfully imported before. **This is useful if you have edited the module source file using an external editor and want to try out the new version without leaving the Python interpreter**.

Comment: so the syntax for import is `import myscript` not `import(myscript)`, while for reload is `reload(myscript)` not `reload myscript`?

Comment: @Tim `reload` is actually a function, so you need to use it like that only, whereas `import` is a keyword in the language.

Comment: Thanks. Is import not a function? What is it? (don't say it is a keyword. the name of a build in function is a keyword too)

Comment: @Tim Keyword is different from a builtin function. The line which has `import` will be normally called as `import` statement. You cannot use that as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

reload builtin is what you actually need:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload