# Reload module from a folder?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Since IPython Notebook does not reload the file after I modified my module, I am trying to reload it. There was a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516783/how-to-reload-python-module-imported-using-from-module-import) on how to do similar things, but my problem is when the .py file is in a subfolder, it does not work.

My original import works like this:

```
from myutils.MyClassFile import MyClass
```

while trying to reload:

```
reload(myutils.MyClassFile)
from myutils.MyClassFile import MyClass
```

I got the error:

```
name 'myutils' is not defined
```

Any suggestion on how to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

In the notebook:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

enables auto reload of all imported modules  that changed for each execution of a cell.

You can exclude modules with:

```
%aimport module_to_exclude
```

Alternatively use:

```
%autoreload 1
```

and whitelist what should be reloaded:

```
%aimport module_to_include
```

Comment: Does this reload all the modules including the big modules that not been modified? Is there a way to specifically reload one module in a folder instead of all modules in the ?  I hope to do so because do not want to reload many large modules (like corpus) every cell run. Thanks.

Comment: Only  modules that changed are actually executed. Added a few more option to my answer.

Comment: I tried the following: "%autoreload 1; %aimport myutils.myeditedmodule; from myutils.myeditedmodule import MyEditedClass; my_new_obj = MyEditedClass();", which did not reload. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try: `import myutils.myeditedmodule.MyEditedClass as MyEditedClass`. Also, you need to change and save the file `myeditedmodule` to force a reload.