# Reload submodule imported in other modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, reload, python-importlib

I have the following issue and I'll share four different .py files to better explain myself. I'm running the code from spyder (not jupyter), python 3.4.
I have a master script "master001.py" from which I execute the code. it looks like this:

```
import sys
before = [str(m) for m in sys.modules]

from importlib import reload
import time
#from child001 import calculation as calc
import child001 
from child002 import calculation_two
from child003 import calculation_three

after = [str(m) for m in sys.modules]
print("########################")   
print([m for m in after if not m in before])
print("########################\n")




stop = False
while stop == False:
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
    reload_child_one = input("reload child 1 function? Enter Y or N\n")
    reload_child_one = reload_child_one.lower()

    if reload_child_one == "y":
        print("Script will try to reload the calculation 1 / child 1 module.")
        time.sleep(1)
        reload(child001)



    reload_child_two = input("reload child 2 function? Enter Y or N\n")
    reload_child_two = reload_child_two.lower()

    if reload_child_two == "y":
        print("Script will try to reload the calculation 2 / child 2 module.")
        time.sleep(1)
        #reload(sys.modules[calculation_two.__module__])
        #del calculation_two
        #from child002 import calculation_two
        #__import__("child002", fromlist='calculation_two')
        calculation_two = reload(sys.modules["child002"]).calculation_two



    print("\n####################################################")
    a = input("Enter number that will be saved in variable 'a' or enter Q to quit prorgam\n")

    if a.lower() == "q" :
        stop = True
        print("\nFunction complted. Script will quit.")
        print("####################################################\n")
        time.sleep(2)

    else:
        try:
            a = int(a)

            print("Master - Launching Child function 'calculation'")
            b = child001.calculation(a)

            print("\nMaster - Inside Master file. Result = b = {}".format(b))
            print("####################################################\n")

            print("Master - Launching Child 2 function 'calculation_two' on input variable")
            c = calculation_two(a)     

            print("\nMaster - Inside Master file. Result = c = {}".format(c))            
            print("####################################################\n")

            print("Master - Launching child 3")
            calculation_three()
            time.sleep(2)

        except:
            print("input value was not a valid number. Please, try again.\n")
            print("####################################################\n")
            time.sleep(2)
```

master001.py calls child001.py to perform a simple calculation:

```
print("wassupp from child 1 !!!")

def calculation(a):

    print("\n----------------------------------------")
    print("Child 1 - function 'calculation' started.")
    print("Child 1 - Operation that will be executed is: input variable + 20")

    result = a + 20

    print("Child 1 - Returning result =  {}".format(result))
    print("----------------------------------------\n")
    return result
```

Then, master001.py calls child002.py in which another simple calculation is performed:

```
print("wassupp from child 2 !!!")

def calculation_two(a):

    print("\n----------------------------------------")
    print("Child 2 - function  'calculation_two' started.")
    print("Child 2 - Operation that will be executed is: input variable + 200")

    result = a + 200

    print("Child 2 - Returning result =  {}".format(result))
    print("----------------------------------------\n")
    return result
```

So far so good. Finally, I have child003.py. in this module I perform a calculation that is actually imported from child002.py

```
from child002 import calculation_two

print("wassupp from child 3 !!!")

def calculation_three():

    print("\n----------------------------------------")
    print("Child 3 function - Calculation will use the one in child 2 applied to value '3'.!\n")

    result = calculation_two(3)

    print("Child 3 - result =  {}".format(result))
    print("----------------------------------------\n")
    return
```

as you can see from running master001.py, when I reload calculation_two using

```
calculation_two = reload(sys.modules["child002"]).calculation_two
```

that works for `calculation_two` run from `child002.py`, however it doesn't reload `calculation_two` called by `child003.py`.

More specifically, if you run `master001.py` and before manually inputting anything change the content of `calculation_two`, then when you get asked

```
reload child 1 function? Enter Y or N
```

you enter N, and when you get asked

```
reload child 2 function? Enter Y or N
```

you enter Y, you will see the value returned by `child003.py` not reflecting the new updated code.

I read [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module) and [How to reload python module imported using `from module import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516783/how-to-reload-python-module-imported-using-from-module-import) they are very helpful but I can't find there a solution to this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with how you imported the function from `child002`:

```
from child002 import calculation_two
```

This creates a reference to the function object in `child003`, and that reference is *not replaced*. Python names are like labels on strings, tied to objects. You can tie multiple labels to an object, and if you want to *replace* that object with another, then you must make sure to re-tie all those labels.

You start with this:

```
sys.modules['child002']
    -> module object created from child002.py
        -> module.__dict__ (the module globals)
            -> module.__dict__['calculation_two']
                    |
                    |
                    +--> function object named calculation_two
                    |
                    |
            -> module.__dict__['calculation_two']
        -> module.__dict__ (the module globals)
    -> module object for child003.py
sys.modules['child003']
```

and when you then reload the `child002` module, Python replaces all the existing globals with new objects, so now you have:

```
sys.modules['child002']
    -> module object created from child002.py
        -> module.__dict__ (the module globals)
            -> module.__dict__['calculation_two']
                    |
                    |
                    +--> *new* function object named calculation_two


                    +--> *old* function object named calculation_two
                    |
                    |
            -> module.__dict__['calculation_two']
        -> module.__dict__ (the module globals)
    -> module object for child003.py
sys.modules['child003']
```

because the `calculation_two` reference in the `child003` module object is an independent label.

You either have to replace that label manually:

```
calculation_two = reload(sys.modules["child002"]).calculation_two
child003.calculation_two = calculation_two
```

or you could just not reference `calculation_two` directly, and instead reference only the `child002` module:

```
import child002

# ...

def calculation_three():
    # ...
    result = child002.calculation_two(3)
```

at which point you have the following relationship:

```
sys.modules['child002']
    -> module object created from child002.py
       ^ -> module.__dict__ (the module globals)
       |    -> module.__dict__['calculation_two']
       |            |
       |            |
       |            +--> function object named calculation_two
       |
       |
       +------------+
                    |
                    |
            -> module.__dict__['child002']
        -> module.__dict__ (the module globals)
    -> module object for child003.py
sys.modules['child003']
```

I can recommend reading [Ned Batchelder's explanation of Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for another perspective on this.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write your useful explanation. Thank you also for sharing that link, I read it all twice, very very helpful. Please, I would have one last question. If I have multiple child scripts, say child005.py, child009.py, child020.py eccetera all using "from child002 import calculation_two", is there a way for me to check how many child I need to update? (Similar to what you mention "child003.calculation_two = calculation_two" but assuming I don't know how many child are referencing calculation_two) Thanks

Comment: @Angelo: You'd have to check all your modules for functions and check their `__module__` attribute. If you want to reload modules regularly, it is much better to only import the module objects elsewhere and not names from those modules.

Comment: thank you Martijn. May I ask what you mean when you say "import the module objects elsewhere" please? Do you mean that, using my code above as example, inside child003.py I should use "import child" instead of "from child002 import calculation_two"? Thanks again for all your help, really appreciated.

Comment: @Angelo: you'd use `import child002`, yes.